# Is it possible to add Kali Linux as a dual-booted operating system without removing Raspbian?

Tags: berryboot

I have a 16GB storage Raspberry Pi 3 running standard Raspbian installed through NOOBS. I'd like to fool around a bit on Kali Linux and was wondering if I could set up a dual boot without erasing Raspbian or any data. I also have an old 1GB microSD but that seems too small to run Kali. I've heard you can use Berryboot or NOOBS to so it but I can't figure out how to do what I'm asking. Finally, I need to be able to choose OS from command line/SSH because I will be running it headless.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the dual-boot in the scenario you described.

Kali Linux is a Debian-based distribution (just like Raspbian) which installs a certain set of packages by default.

For most use cases it doesn't have any features (code) on its own, and does not require these packages to be running specifically under Kali Linux.

You can install your required packages with APT, configure, and run them on Raspbian.

An additional advantage would be that you would learn the tools dependencies and configuration.